# GridLookUpEdit Set Index

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

On a `GridLookUpEdit` I want to change position with two buttons
I can get Index by

```
XGridLookUpEdit.Properties.GetIndexByKeyValue(XGridLookUpEdit.EditValue);
```

but I do not know how to set it

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x = XGridLookUpEdit.Properties.GetIndexByKeyValue(XGridLookUpEdit.EditValue);
XGridLookUpEdit.EditValue = 
    XGridLookUpEdit.Properties.View.GetRowCellValue(x + 1, "id");
```